# Nestjs | cache-manager | TypeError: common_1.ConfigurableModuleBuilder is not a constructor

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-config

While I'm trying to implement Nestjs caching in my dummy project, I'm facing the following error:-

```
node_modules/@nestjs/cache-manager/dist/cache.module-definition.js:6
_a = new common_1.ConfigurableModuleBuilder({
     ^
TypeError: common_1.ConfigurableModuleBuilder is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nikhil/Documents/ProjRepos/Practice/nest-caching-hands-on/node_modules/@nestjs/cache-manager/dist/cache.module-definition.js:6:6)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1033:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:868:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1057:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/nikhil/Documents/ProjRepos/Practice/nest-caching-hands-on/node_modules/@nestjs/cache-manager/dist/cache.constants.js:4:35)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1155:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1209:10)
```

I checked for version mismatches, tried deleting node_modules, cleaning yarn cache, tinkering with the typescript version etc but nothing seems to work. I keep getting the same error. This is just a basic implementation of nestjs cache-manager that's provided in the documentation [NestJS Caching](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/caching). I followed it verbatim.

##### app.module.ts

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { MongooseModule, MongooseModuleFactoryOptions } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { TodoModule } from './todo/todo.module';
import { ConfigModule, ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { CacheModule } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot(),
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [ConfigModule],
      inject: [ConfigService],
      useFactory: async (configService: ConfigService) => {
        const obj: MongooseModuleFactoryOptions = {
          uri: configService.get<string>(`MONGODB_URI`),
        };

        return obj;
      },
    }),
    CacheModule.register({
      isGlobal: true,
    }),

    TodoModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

##### todo.controller.ts

```js
import {
  Controller,
  Get,
  Post,
  Body,
  Patch,
  Param,
  Delete,
  Inject,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { TodoService } from './todo.service';
import { CreateTodoDto } from './dto/create-todo.dto';
import { UpdateTodoDto } from './dto/update-todo.dto';
import { CACHE_MANAGER } from '@nestjs/cache-manager';
import { Cache } from 'cache-manager';

@Controller('todo')
export class TodoController {
  constructor(
    private readonly todoService: TodoService,

    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER)
    private cacheManager: Cache,
  ) {}

  @Post()
  create(@Body() createTodoDto: CreateTodoDto) {
    return this.todoService.create(createTodoDto);
  }

  @Get()
  async findAll() {
    await this.cacheManager.set('hello', 'world!');

    const val = await this.cacheManager.get('hello');

    console.log({
      val,
    });

    return this.todoService.findAll();
  }

  @Get(':id')
  findOne(@Param('id') id: string) {
    return this.todoService.findOne(+id);
  }

  @Patch(':id')
  update(@Param('id') id: string, @Body() updateTodoDto: UpdateTodoDto) {
    return this.todoService.update(+id, updateTodoDto);
  }

  @Delete(':id')
  remove(@Param('id') id: string) {
    return this.todoService.remove(+id);
  }
}
```

##### todo.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { CreateTodoDto } from './dto/create-todo.dto';
import { UpdateTodoDto } from './dto/update-todo.dto';
import { InjectConnection, InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Todo } from 'src/schemas/todo.schema';
import { Connection, Model } from 'mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class TodoService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(Todo.name) private todoModel: Model<Todo>,
    @InjectConnection() private connection: Connection,
  ) {}

  async create(createCatDto: CreateTodoDto): Promise<Todo> {
    const createdTodo = new this.todoModel(createCatDto);
    return createdTodo.save();
  }

  async findAll(): Promise<Todo[]> {
    return this.todoModel.find().exec();
  }

  findOne(id: number) {
    return `This action returns a #${id} todo`;
  }

  update(id: number, updateTodoDto: UpdateTodoDto) {
    return `This action updates a #${id} todo`;
  }

  remove(id: number) {
    return `This action removes a #${id} todo`;
  }
}
```

##### todo.module.ts

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TodoService } from './todo.service';
import { TodoController } from './todo.controller';
import { MongooseModule } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { Todo, TodoSchema } from '../schemas/todo.schema';

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: Todo.name,
        schema: TodoSchema,
      },
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [TodoController],
  providers: [TodoService],
})
export class TodoModule {}
```

##### package.json

```json
{
  "name": "nest-caching-hands-on",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Trying out Nestjs caching",
  "author": {
    "name": "Nikhil Choudhary"
  },
  "private": true,
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cache-manager": "^2.0.1",
    "@nestjs/common": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/config": "^3.0.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "*",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^10.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/cache-manager": "^4.0.2",
    "cache-manager": "^5.2.3",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
    "mongoose": "^7.3.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^8.0.0",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/jest": "27.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.0.0",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.11",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.0.0",
    "eslint": "^8.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.2.5",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.20",
    "supertest": "^6.1.3",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.3",
    "ts-node": "^10.0.0",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^3.10.1",
    "typescript": "4.7.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "ts"
    ],
    "rootDir": "src",
    "testRegex": ".*\\.spec\\.ts$",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(t|j)s$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "**/*.(t|j)s"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "../coverage",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

Comment: show us your tsconfig file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `@nestjs/*` packages. Common, core, and platform-express should *at least* be on v9, preferably v10.